# Как отправить POST запрос с xml-содержими в формдата с помощью python-requests?

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, curl, requests

Есть следующая веб-страница

http://www.nasdaqomxnordic.com/shares

Мне нужно отправить `POST` запрос на `Python (3.8+)`

[image]
[image]
[image]

Я пробовал c помощью курла также

**cUrl**

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type:text/xml;charset=UTF-8" -d @xml.query http://www.nasdaqomxnordic.com/webproxy/DataFeedProxy.aspx
```

и это

```
curl -X POST -H 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' -d '{"xmlquery": "%3Cpost%3E%0A%3Cparam+name%3D%22Exchange%22+value%3D%22NMF%22%2F%3E%0A%3Cparam+name%3D%22SubSystem%22+value%3D%22Prices%22%2F%3E%0A%3Cparam+name%3D%22Action%22+value%3D%22GetMarket%22%2F%3E%0A%3Cparam+name%3D%22inst__a%22+value%3D%220%2C1%2C2%2C5%2C21%2C23%22%2F%3E%0A%3Cparam+name%3D%22ext_xslt%22+value%3D%22%2FnordicV3%2Finst_table_shares_ge.xsl%22%2F%3E%0A%3Cparam+name%3D%22Market%22+value%3D%22L%3AINET%3AH7053910%22%2F%3E%0A%3Cparam+name%3D%22inst__an%22+value%3D%22id%2Csectrid%2Cnm%2Cfnm%2Ccr%2Clsp%2Ctp%2Cch%2Cchp%2Cbp%2Cap%2Ctv%2Cto%2Chlp%2Clists%2Cnote%2Cpmkt%2Cmktc%2Cisin%2Cst%2Cslc%2Cstc%22%2F%3E%0A%3Cparam+name%3D%22inst__e%22+value%3D%2213%22%2F%3E%0A%3Cparam+name%3D%22issuer__e%22+value%3D%224%22%2F%3E%0A%3Cparam+name%3D%22issuer__a%22+value%3D%222%22%2F%3E%0A%3Cparam+name%3D%22Lang%22+value%3D%22en%22%2F%3E%0A%3Cparam+name%3D%22XPath%22+value%3D%22%2F%2Finst%5B%40tp%3D'S'+or+%40tp%3D'ER'+and+%40st!%3D'Subscription+right'%5D%22%2F%3E%0A%3Cparam+name%3D%22ext_xslt_sortattribute%22+value%3D%22fnm%22%2F%3E%0A%3Cparam+name%3D%22ext_xslt_lang%22+value%3D%22en%22%2F%3E%0A%3Cparam+name%3D%22ext_xslt_tableId%22+value%3D%22searchSharesListTable%22%2F%3E%0A%3Cparam+name%3D%22ext_xslt_hiddenattrs%22+value%3D%22%2Clists%2Chlp%2Ctp%2Cisin%2Cnote%2Cmktc%2Cpmkt%2Cst%2Cslc%2Cstc%2C%22%2F%3E%0A%3Cparam+name%3D%22ext_xslt_tableClass%22+value%3D%22tablesorter%22%2F%3E%0A%3Cparam+name%3D%22ext_xslt_options%22+value%3D%22%2Cnoflag%2Csectoridicon%2Ctruncate%2C%22%2F%3E%0A%3Cparam+name%3D%22DefaultDecimals%22+value%3D%22false%22%2F%3E%0A%3Cparam+name%3D%22app%22+value%3D%22%2Fshares%22%2F%3E%0A%3C%2Fpost%3E"}' http://www.nasdaqomxnordic.com/webproxy/DataFeedProxy.aspx
```

**OPTIONS** request

```
m0nte-cr1st0@jitsi:~$ curl -X OPTIONS -v --request-target "http://www.nasdaqomxnordic.com/webproxy/DataFeedProxy.aspx" http://www.nasdaqomxnordic.com/webproxy/DataFeedProxy.aspx/
*   Trying 23.79.149.128:80...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to www.nasdaqomxnordic.com (23.79.149.128) port 80 (#0)
> OPTIONS http://www.nasdaqomxnordic.com/webproxy/DataFeedProxy.aspx HTTP/1.1
> Host: www.nasdaqomxnordic.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
> Accept: */*
```

Также с помощью `requests`
**Python**

```
>>> import requests
>>>
>>>
>>> payload = {'xmlquery': "%3Cpost%3E%0A%3Cparam+name%3D%22Exchange%22+value%3D%22NMF%22%2F%3E%0A%3Cparam+name%3D%22SubSystem%22+value%3D%22Prices%22%2F%3E%0A%3Cparam+name%3D%22Action%22+value%3D%22GetMarket%22%2F%3E%0A%3Cparam+name%3D%22inst__a%22+value%3D%220%2C1%2C2%2C5%2C21%2C23%22%2F%3E%0A%3Cparam+name%3D%22ext_xslt%22+value%3D%22%2FnordicV3%2Finst_table_shares_ge.xsl%22%2F%3E%0A%3Cparam+name%3D%22Market%22+value%3D%22L%3AINET%3AH7053910%22%2F%3E%0A%3Cparam+name%3D%22inst__an%22+value%3D%22id%2Csectrid%2Cnm%2Cfnm%2Ccr%2Clsp%2Ctp%2Cch%2Cchp%2Cbp%2Cap%2Ctv%2Cto%2Chlp%2Clists%2Cnote%2Cpmkt%2Cmktc%2Cisin%2Cst%2Cslc%2Cstc%22%2F%3E%0A%3Cparam+name%3D%22inst__e%22+value%3D%2213%22%2F%3E%0A%3Cparam+name%3D%22issuer__e%22+value%3D%224%22%2F%3E%0A%3Cparam+name%3D%22issuer__a%22+value%3D%222%22%2F%3E%0A%3Cparam+name%3D%22Lang%22+value%3D%22en%22%2F%3E%0A%3Cparam+name%3D%22XPath%22+value%3D%22%2F%2Finst%5B%40tp%3D'S'+or+%40tp%3D'ER'+and+%40st!%3D'Subscription+right'%5D%22%2F%3E%0A%3Cparam+name%3D%22ext_xslt_sortattribute%22+value%3D%22fnm%22%2F%3E%0A%3Cparam+name%3D%22ext_xslt_lang%22+value%3D%22en%22%2F%3E%0A%3Cparam+name%3D%22ext_xslt_tableId%22+value%3D%22searchSharesListTable%22%2F%3E%0A%3Cparam+name%3D%22ext_xslt_hiddenattrs%22+value%3D%22%2Clists%2Chlp%2Ctp%2Cisin%2Cnote%2Cmktc%2Cpmkt%2Cst%2Cslc%2Cstc%2C%22%2F%3E%0A%3Cparam+name%3D%22ext_xslt_tableClass%22+value%3D%22tablesorter%22%2F%3E%0A%3Cparam+name%3D%22ext_xslt_options%22+value%3D%22%2Cnoflag%2Csectoridicon%2Ctruncate%2C%22%2F%3E%0A%3Cparam+name%3D%22DefaultDecimals%22+value%3D%22false%22%2F%3E%0A%3Cparam+name%3D%22app%22+value%3D%22%2Fshares%22%2F%3E%0A%3C%2Fpost%3E"}
>>> headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0', 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'}
>>> 
>>> session = requests.Session()
>>> r = session.post('http://www.nasdaqomxnordic.com/webproxy/DataFeedProxy.aspx', headers=headers,data=payload)
```

Но в ответ ничего не получаю. Идет обрыв по тайм-ауту

Comment: json=payload в r = session.post() пробовали? или file=payload

Comment: там такое ощущение, что в ключ `xmlquery` записан `xml`. так что `file` вряд ли подойдет. `json` сейчас попробую.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Работает, попробуйте:

```
import requests


data = {
    'xmlquery': """<post>
<param name="Exchange" value="NMF"/>
<param name="SubSystem" value="Prices"/>
<param name="Action" value="GetMarket"/>
<param name="inst__a" value="0,1,2,5,21,23"/>
<param name="ext_xslt" value="/nordicV3/inst_table_shares_ge.xsl"/>
<param name="Market" value="L:INET:H7053910"/>
<param name="inst__an" value="id,sectrid,nm,fnm,cr,lsp,tp,ch,chp,bp,ap,tv,to,hlp,lists,note,pmkt,mktc,isin,st,slc,stc"/>
<param name="inst__e" value="13"/>
<param name="issuer__e" value="4"/>
<param name="issuer__a" value="2"/>
<param name="Lang" value="en"/>
<param name="XPath" value="//inst[@tp='S' or @tp='ER' and @st!='Subscription right']"/>
<param name="ext_xslt_sortattribute" value="fnm"/>
<param name="ext_xslt_lang" value="en"/>
<param name="ext_xslt_tableId" value="searchSharesListTable"/>
<param name="ext_xslt_hiddenattrs" value=",lists,hlp,tp,isin,note,mktc,pmkt,st,slc,stc,"/>
<param name="ext_xslt_tableClass" value="tablesorter"/>
<param name="ext_xslt_options" value=",noflag,sectoridicon,truncate,"/>
<param name="DefaultDecimals" value="false"/>
<param name="app" value="/shares"/>
</post>"""
}
headers = {
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
}

session = requests.session()
session.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:87.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/87.'

rs = session.post('http://www.nasdaqomxnordic.com/webproxy/DataFeedProxy.aspx', data=data, headers=headers)
print(rs)

print(rs.text[:100])
# <table id="searchSharesListTable" class="tablesorter" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
```

Comment: Всё дело в `X-Requested-With` Oo ;(

Comment: Не могли бы объяснить, зачем этот заголовок? Я нашёл ответ на англоязычном ресурсе - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17478731 . Но как-то сложно там всё. Буду очень признателен

Comment: @Dima, его наличие говорит серверу, что запрос был через AJAX и некоторым серверам это важно, хотя по факту, это просто флаг, ведь ajax тот же самый post запрос